# Playframework 2.5.3 ebean package com.avaje.ebean does not exist

Tags: java, playframework

I was trying to replicate the documentation at:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaEbean

I setup everything like it was mentioned in the documentation.

```
project\plugins.sbt: addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")

build.sbt:

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc, 
    cache, 
    javaWs,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)

build.properties:
 sbt.version=0.13.11

 application.conf:
  ebean.default="models.*"
```

still when I use

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
```

in my model class, I get exception that javax.persistence and com.avaje does not exist. What could be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have not add the dependencies into your sbt file. You can fix this problem by adding these dependencies like this

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc, 
    cache, 
    javaWs,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
    "org.avaje" % "ebean" % "2.7.3",
    "javax.persistence" % "persistence-api" % "1.0.2"
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jerry. This really fixed the problem. I was wondering is there a convention on how to declare the dependencies. How do I know the what to defined. Is there any documentation you could point me towards?

Comment: I found the way how to figure out the SBT naming convention. Search for the package in http://mvnrepository.com/ and then select the appropriate package. On the result page there are many tabs like "Maven, Gradle, SBT". Select the SBT tab and it will show the correct syntax for the package. I really appreciate your help Jerry!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Though accepted answer is a nice quick fix, it didn't really solve the problem (properly) for me. I have jumped from Play 2.4.6 to 2.6.1 (so I've never had to deal with 2.5.x) and I have never needed to declare ebean as a dependency, only as a plugin.

I'm using `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.2")` in plugins.sbt and `lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,PlayEbean)` in build.sbt on Play 2.6.1. Even though expecting ebean in `com.avaje.ebean` is logical, **it has in fact moved to io.ebean package** when using the plugin somewhere between 2.4.6 and 2.6.1. If I add a library dependency as well, it's also possible to import ebean from `com.avaje.ebean`, but I don't think that's a recommended way.